# How to resolve JsonParseException for InfluxDB sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, influxdb

Here is json data in test topic [kafka]

[image]

This is a connector property

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8089/connectors/influxdb-sink-test-20210615/config \
    -d '{
        "connector.class"               : "io.confluent.influxdb.InfluxDBSinkConnector",
        "value.converter"               : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "key.converter"                 : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "topics"                        : "test3",
        "influxdb.url"                  : "http://localhost:8086",
        "influxdb.db"                   : "exemDB",
        "measurement.name.format"       : "${topic}"
    }'
```

An exception is raised in the Kafka connector because the tags field is not converted properly. How can I properly convert the tags field?

Removing the tags field and producing data on the topic normally inserts data into the influxDB.

---

This is Exception..

If i remove the field tag and produce it, it works well on influxdb. How can I fill in the tags field?

```
[2021-06-17 09:24:59,521] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=influxdb-sink-tcore-test-20210615-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:490)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:334)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"dataType":"numeric","parentResourceId":0,"resourceId":1037092,"resourceUUID":"1037092","resourceName":"tcore-master-01","resourceTypeId":5,"resourceTypeName":"물리서버","resourceLocation":"미지정","ip":"localhost","tags":"[{"tagId":0,"tagValueId":0,"tag":"미지정","value":"미지정"},{"tagId":7,"tagValueId":2103044,"tag":"물리서버","value":"tcore-master-01"},{"tagId":52,"tagValueId":2103045,"tag":"미지정","value":"tcore-master01"}]","metricSeq":930,"metricName":"command_"[truncated 279 bytes]; line: 1, column: 242]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"dataType":"numeric","parentResourceId":0,"resourceId":1037092,"resourceUUID":"1037092","resourceName":"tcore-master-01","resourceTypeId":5,"resourceTypeName":"물리서버","resourceLocation":"미지정","ip":"localhost","tags":"[{"tagId":0,"tagValueId":0,"tag":"미지정","value":"미지정"},{"tagId":7,"tagValueId":2103044,"tag":"물리서버","value":"tcore-master-01"},{"tagId":52,"tagValueId":2103045,"tag":"미지정","value":"tcore-master01"}]","metricSeq":930,"metricName":"command_"[truncated 279 bytes]; line: 1, column: 242]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:669)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:567)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:980)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:247)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:68)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4056)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2571)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:332)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:490)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2021-06-17 09:24:59,522] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=influxdb-sink-tcore-test-20210615-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
[2021-06-17 09:24:59,522] INFO Closing InfluxDB client. (io.confluent.influxdb.sink.writer.InfluxDBWriter:406)
```

Comment: Your data isn't valid JSON - `JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries`

Comment: Yes, I already know the content. What I want is to use the Json data I attached above that type.

Comment: I understand the question, but according to the error, some record in your Kafka topic cannot be parsed as JSON, not because tags field exists or not. Can you state how you are producing the data?